# What should a girl do who is regretting messaging a boy she knows on Facebook from an anonymous account? After stopping this, is she a bad girl?

Tags: men-women, internet

It's all about a friend of mine. She became interested in a boy but she kept all this in her heart. She had not showed him all this.

One day she saw his ID on Facebook. Then she became emotional and she texted him. After talking with him for three days she realized her guilt. She had not even told the boy her real name her identity and anything about her. She was texting him from a fake ID. After 3 or 4 days she stopped this, but she thinks that she did very wrong and she has regrets. She fears what would happen to her even though she had stopped this. Actually she also prohibit others by doing such nonsense acts.

I want to ask that after stopping this, would she be a bad girl?

Comment: Why r u not answering this.it's a big issue for her

Comment: Please take some time to improve the question and delete the comments (or) please delete this question. See also: "[How do I ask](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)"

Comment: She has to sincerely repent and make tawbah.

Comment: @servant hmm ok

Comment: And this is not about your friend, it's about u, the way you are asking this question, i realize that you are asking question with your friend name

Comment: Is chatting with an opposite sex needs Towbah!!! What are you thinking about Islam!! Is It a SIN????!!! Her GUILT?!?!?!

Comment: I think these ideas will ruin our dear Islam. Please be reasonable and don't be blind...

Answer (score 1):

```
              In the name of Allah, the most compassionate, the most merciful
```

As you’ve asked

> What after leaving the sin?
>
> … now she also prohibit others by doing such nonsense acts.I want to
>   ask that after leaving all this, would she be a bad girl?

Perhaps, the most appropriate the most constructive verse of the Quran (as a related verse) can be as follows:

> إِلَّا مَن تَابَ وَآمَنَ وَعَمِلَ عَمَلًا صَالِحًا فَأُولَـٰئِكَ
>   يُبَدِّلُ اللَّـهُ سَيِّئَاتِهِمْ حَسَنَاتٍ ۗ وَكَانَ اللَّـهُ
>   غَفُورًا رَّحِيمًا ﴿٧٠
>
> Except for those who repent, believe and do righteous work. For them
>   Allah will replace their evil deeds with good. And ever is Allah
>   Forgiving and Merciful. / (25:70)

As a result, she cannot be named as a bad girl in case that she has repented (as a real repent), and Allah will forgive her as it is said in the holy Quran that

> ... And ever is Allah Forgiving and Merciful. / (25:70)

---

**References:**

- [tanzil.net](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/25:70)
- [www.tebyan.net](http://www.tebyan.net/newindex.aspx?pid=112884)

Comment: dear sir, Do you also think talking with another human(beside any gender) is a sin?? I'm really confused ?!?!

Comment: Not every time and everywhere. It would be haram in some cases such as: if you feel talking with ... is making you some or much feeling of sin ... / or ever might to lead to  in ... in the future ....   / Thanks for being curious regarding these significant points...

Comment: Thanks for your illustration. I think in this situation that girl love the boy and not talking him in the way of lust.

Comment: There's a quote from Ayatalla Bahjat (PBUH) that says if a girl and boy love each other in a such way that completely decide to marry each other, it's not concern that touch each others hand. In this way I say If two one love each other in marry way, It wouldn't be as rigid as you say.

Comment: I haven't precisely heard it before (although it would be trusted if Ayatollah Bahjat said ...). I have heard a similar issue that: you can see hair (or apparently more than hair ...) of the girl IF YOU REALLY INTEND TO GET MARRIED TO. (Since anyhow you'll live with her, and you ought to see her unveiled shape ...AFAIK)

Comment: Yes, It's true. As you claimed " IF REALLY INTEND". but I think you should include this " if she really intend to marry him then she has no SIN in her work." . It clarify subjects of acting rigid in this situations. You claimed she is a sinner as I read your answer.

Comment: Firstly I reckon it has not mentioned for the issue of marriage. It said "She got interested in a boy but she kept all this in her heart" ____ Secondly, indicating of the issue of seeing ... (for suit (proposing)) doesn't mean that girls and boys ... (by an apparent think of suit ..)) , haply (AFAIK) it is said as the step of Suit (khaastegari) or something like that. ____ Otherwise I reckon a high percentage of girl-boys relations would be claimed by the intention of marriage, but oftennnnnnnnnnn of them never ...